# Name of General Software Position

Tags: software-development, job-description, software, team-role

We are attempting to create a position for an individual who creates custom software with VBA, SQL and possible PHP, HTML, CSS, Javascript to help across our departments with things like automating worksheets, creating interfaces through which our data can be accessed, etc.  We were wondering what such a role would be called?  I mentioned Software Developer because it seemed the most generic and able to reach across VBA through HTML, but my manager said it made her think of "Web Developer" which she didn't like and felt was too restrictive.  Most of the work will be for back-end software.

Would "Software Developer" be the best role name for that description or is there something else?  My manager thought "Database Developer" but to me that means specifically either developing databases.

Comment: "Software Developer" sound just fine. Possibly coupled with "end to end" or "full stack"?

Comment: You might consider allowing the new employee to pick their own title (within reason, of course).  They may not want to be saddled with 'web' in their title, for example, if their long term goals aren't web development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Software engineer/developer is the general catch-all term for software engineering family of jobs and the best fit for your mix of skills.**

You do have a mix of more specialized roles in your description I would advise you to narrow the job description:

1. Automating worksheets with VBA and SQL sounds like Data/Business Analyst.
2. PHP, HTML and CSS sounds more like Web Development.